# Getting a more detailed error message when using JSON.parse with Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am looking for a way to get a more detailed error message when parsing invalid JSON (text)

my JSON files dont use the double quoted property names, and might contain expressions, and template literals

Comment: Well you do not have JSON if your files have that...... plenty of JSON validators out there that spit out error messages.

Answer (score -1):

after exploring several parsers, i found that the simplest way to do this is to save JSON to a file, and "require" it.

of course i would not use this when i'm parsing JSON received on an HTTP endpoint, but it works great when u are reading JSON files, configuration, JSON schema's etc...

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')

const displayJSONError = source => {
    const filePath = path.resolve('displayJSONError_tmp.js')
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, `const c = ${source}`)

    try {
        require(filePath)
    } catch (error) {
        let lineNumber = 1
        console.error(`error:${error.message}\nline: ${error.stack.split(`${filePath}:`).pop().split('SyntaxError:')[0]}\n${source.split('\n').map(line => `${lineNumber++} ${line}`).join('\n')}`)
    }

    fs.unlinkSync(filePath)
}

try {
    JSON.parse(aString)
} catch (error) {
    displayJSONError(aString)
}
```

this code displays the faulty JSON with linenumbers, highlights the location of the error and displays the line number

Comment: This will not show syntax errors in `JSON` but in `JS`